# Azure Bicep from DevOps - Scope Microsoft.Resources/deployments Error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a bicep file that I'm able to run successfully from vscode. I'd like to run the same file from Azure DevOps.

This is the yaml from the DevOps pipeline:

```
task: AzureCLI@2    
displayName: Deploy Template
inputs:
  azureSubscription: ${{variables.azureSubscription}}
  scriptType: pscore
  scriptLocation: inlineScript
  inlineScript: az deployment group create `
    --resource-group rg-utrngen-${{variables.env}}-001 `
    --template-file bicep/utrngen.main.bicep `
    --parameters bicep/utrngen.parameters.${{variables.env}}.json
```

This fails with the following error:

> The client '<objid-of-the-aad-appreg-for-the-devops-svc-con>' with
> object id '<objid-of-the-aad-appreg-for-the-devops-svc-con>' does not
> have authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action' over scope
> '/subscriptions/<sub-id-being-deployed-to>/resourcegroups/rg-utrngen-dev-001/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/utrngen.main'
> or the scope is invalid

I'm using the same DevOps service connection as for many other pipelines that run ok. I'm not sure what the error is trying to tell me?

Comment: what is the role of you service principal over the resource group ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, it is "owner"

Comment: are you sure you are targetting the right subscription ?

Comment: Good question! I'm not sure how "az deployment group create" decides on the target subscription? The value for the --resource-group parameter is correct, it is an rg in the "dev" subscription

Comment: My bad Thomas, it was a typo!

Comment: Good to here you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this error was the line:

> --resource-group rg-utrngen-${{variables.env}}-001

The name of the resource group was spelled incorrectly, it should have been rg-utrngerator